# I try to put spinner object on tab panel in kivy but not working, help me

Tags: python, kivy

So this is the basic code of my tab item.

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
Builder.load_string("""

<Test>:
size_hint: .8, .5
pos_hint: {'center_x': .4, 'center_y': .3}
do_default_tab: False

TabbedPanelItem:
    text: 'Tab 1'
    Label:
        text: 'Syntax'


TabbedPanelItem:
    text: 'Changeover'


TabbedPanelItem:
    text: 'Map'

""")


class Test(TabbedPanel):
pass


class TabbedPanelApp(App):
def build(self):
    return Test()

if __name__ == '__main__':
TabbedPanelApp().run()
```

and i want to insert spinner on Tab 1, how to make it work? this is my spinner code.

```
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivy.properties import ListProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.uix.button import Button
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class MultiSelectSpinner(Button):


dropdown = ObjectProperty(None)


values = ListProperty([])


selected_values = ListProperty([])


def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    self.bind(dropdown=self.update_dropdown)
    self.bind(values=self.update_dropdown)
    super(MultiSelectSpinner, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.bind(on_release=self.toggle_dropdown)

def toggle_dropdown(self, *args):
    if self.dropdown.parent:
        self.dropdown.dismiss()
    else:
        self.dropdown.open(self)

def update_dropdown(self, *args):
    if not self.dropdown:
        self.dropdown = DropDown()
    values = self.values
    if values:
        if self.dropdown.children:
            self.dropdown.clear_widgets()
        for value in values:
            b = Factory.MultiSelectOption(text=value)
            b.bind(state=self.select_value)
            self.dropdown.add_widget(b)

def select_value(self, instance, value):
    if value == 'down':
        if instance.text not in self.selected_values:
            self.selected_values.append(instance.text)
    else:
        if instance.text in self.selected_values:
            self.selected_values.remove(instance.text)

def on_selected_values(self, instance, value):
    if value:
        self.text = ', '.join(value)
    else:
        self.text = ''


kv = '''
BoxLayout:
orientation: 'vertical'
size_hint: .7, .6
pos_hint: {'center_x': .3, 'center_y': .7}
do_default_tab: False

BoxLayout:

    Label:
        text: 'Food Type'

    MultiSelectSpinner:
        values: 'Fried Chicken', 'Burger'

<MultiSelectOption@ToggleButton>:
size_hint: 8, None
height: '40dp'


'''

runTouchApp(Builder.load_string(kv))
```

i need abit pointer please
i try to merge the code but not working.
glad if someone can help

Answer (score 0):

i think its best if you create a custom TabbledPanelItem. and then implement that spinner in it.forgive my indentation

```
class Mod(TabbedPanelItem):
    one = ObjectProperty(None)

def __init__(self,**kwargs):
    super(Mod,self).__init__(**kwargs)

def on_touch_down(self, touch):
    if self.state == 'down':
        # dispatch to children, not to self
        for child in self.children:
            child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch)
        return
    else:
        super(Mod, self).on_touch_down(touch)

def on_release(self, *largs):
    if self.parent:
        self.parent.tabbed_panel.switch_to(self)
        print(self.parent.children)
        lola = MultiSelectSpinner()
        lola.toggle_dropdown()


    else:
        # tab removed before we could switch to it. Switch back to
        # previous tab
        self.panel.switch_to(self.panel.current_tab)
```